# Resultados de acceder con otra cuenta de linux

Tags: oracle

Cuando intento conectar al sqlplus user/password con una cuenta de SO distinta al que es dueño del motor de base de datos oracle y el sistema operativos es Linux, obtengo el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
[usernew@server ~]$ sqlplus usuario/password

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Jun 3 13:22:13 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12547: TNS:lost contact

Enter user-name: ^C
```

Comment: Cuando intentas ingresar como sysdba puedes hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas seguro es que tus variables de ambientes no esten bien configuradas.

Intenta desde los 2 usuarios:

echo $ORACLE_HOME
echo $ORACLE_SID
echo $PATH

Si son diferentes,  al usuario que no es dueño configura los mismos valores que el usuario dueño.